# Positioning absolute div in fixed container

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am trying to make my logo stay fixed on my header. I dont want it to go past the home tab when the screen size is adjusted. How can I do this?

```
<div class="header_menu">
    <div class="main_top">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="wrapper"> 
                <div class="cssmenu"><div class="headerlogo_tag"><img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/112/5/6/logo_by_destinyjade-d7fmi7c.png" width="174" height="174" alt=""></div>
                  <ul>
                       <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>      
                       <li class="last"><a href="news.html"><span>News</span></a></li>
                       <li class="last"><a href="team.html"><span>Team</span></a></li>
                       <li class="last"><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
                       <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerlogo_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.headerlogo_tag {
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     left: 255px;
     top: -10px;
     z-index: 1000;
}

.header_menu {
    background: #000000;
    background-image: url(http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/112/b/a/header_bg_by_destinyjade-d7flhv4.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Using a comment before the doctype can mess things up. (`<!--A Design by W3layouts`, etc)

Comment: Oh really? I didn't realize thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.headerlogo_tag { position: absolute }
```

Get rid of that. You do not need position absolute. You do not want position absolute. Position absolute is not to be misused like this. What did it ever do to you? :(

Seriously, if unless you want an absolutely positioned element, don't use one. And you almost never need an absolute element, since DOM is based off of HTML ([v2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/)) which is based on free-flowing text.

Comment: Thank you! I removed it and it helped keep it fixed but now there is a black bar showing up?

Comment: `.headerlogo_tag { height: 0 }`

Comment: Wow wonderful! Thank you so much for all of your help! It was really insightful!

Comment: @Destiny [This](http://web-dev-lover.blogspot.in/2014/01/css-position-property.html) might help you understand positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:relative;` to your `.wrap`.

Then your `.headerlogo_tag` will stay in an absolute position relative to `.wrap`.

```
.wrap{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:80%;
  position: relative;
}
.headerlogo_tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

You might want to experiment with the positioning a little bit more but that's the idea.